# how to hide Clock and Control Panel in Windows-CE 5.0 (by C# or any registry value)

Tags: c#, registry, windows-ce

how to hide the Clock and Control Panel in Windows-CE 5.0

by C# code  or any registry value  ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that by clock and control panel you mean the task bar?

If so, we use the following helpers to hide/show the whole bar.  It is quite a 'hard' method, though, in that it hides it for the system, not just your app, so you need to show it again as your app closes:

```
    private const int SW_HIDE = 0x0000;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 0x0005;

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowW(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nTaskShow);

    public static void HideStartBar()
    {
        IntPtr handle = FindWindowW("HHTaskBar", string.Empty);
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
    }

    public static void ShowStartBar()
    {
        IntPtr handle = FindWindowW("HHTaskBar", string.Empty);
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
    }
```